# R: map.match on world database returns "Error in tolower(patterns) : object 'patterns' not found"

Tags: r, maps

I'm attempting to create a spatial map using the maps package in R. However, when I try to use `match.map()` using the `world` database, I receive the following error:

> Error in tolower(patterns) : object 'patterns' not found

Here is a sample of the code that is failing with the above error:

```
match.map("world", "USA")
```

However, performing a match on another database (e.g. `state` or `legacy_world`) works just fine.

```
match.map("state", "Iowa")

match.map("legacy_world", "USA")
```

In addition, if I use the map function and specify a region to be matched, this also works as expected.

```
map("world", "USA")
```

So the issue appears to be limited to just the `map.match()` function and the `world` database.

I'm using Windows 7 64-bit, R 3.2.2, RStudio 0.99.489 and the latest maps package (i.e. 3.0.0-2).

If anyone has any thoughts on what would cause this issue, please let me know.  In the meantime, I'm going to look into a workaround involving extracting the names from the world database using the `namesonly()` command and performing an external match on the names to get the polygon indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matthew,

Oops. This is a bug in the code which indeed is triggered only for the 'world' database. The bugfix version will be maps 3.0.1 and should appear on CRAN within a day or two.

Until then, since the bug is only triggered for 'world', you can try to get around it by creating a temporary polygon database.

```
world <- map(plot=FALSE,resolution=0)

match.map(world,'USA')  # notice : world is unquoted
```

You'll get a warning (which will also be fixed in 3.0.1) but it seems to work OK.

My apologies for the bug.

Alex

Comment: No problem at all, Alex.  I'm just glad we were able to identify the issue quickly and that it appears to be a relatively easy fix. I'll keep an eye out for the bug fix release. Thanks!